# Can I post a temporary file name of the file that is being uploaded using jquery

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, upload

I need to post a form which includes personal details and I need to upload an attachment file also I need to achieve this using AJAX.

How can I upload a file using AJAX , I need to post the personal detail as well as upload a file at the same time using AJAX ,  how can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't upload files with AJAX because you can't do multi-part encoded requests - that's a limitation of the XMLHttpRequest API.

Workarounds for this typically involve using an IFRAME that is the target of a form that handles the actual file upload as a separate sub-process to the overall form.  The response loaded in the IFRAME then communicates back to the DOM in the parent/calling page with information about the uploaded file.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a hidden iframe on the page

```
<iframe name="iframe1" ... />
```

And the change the target on your form to post to the iframe

```
<Form traget="iframe1" ...>...</form>
```

You can upload and post the data to the page.  You can also use javascript (JQuery) to get hook into the events of the iframe.

To get a upload progress meter, use the php uploadprogress module.  It works great!
http://pecl.php.net/package/uploadprogress
and
http://bluga.net/projects/uploadProgressMeter/

Here is a link i found that may help:
http://www.finalwebsites.com/forums/topic/php-ajax-upload-example